# Sorting table in polygon shapefile in order of intersecting line?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I have 119 parcels that intersect a polyline.  I want to be able to sort the table to see if any of the land owners in the parcels have have consecutive ownership along the line.

Is there a way to do this, or some other process to see the order?

Comment: Probably going to want to look into linear referencing. Might be able to do it with some sorting/querying based on address fields if you have those. If you want truly consecutive (immediately adjacent, not other owners in between), you might extract parcels touching the road then dissolve on owner without multiparts. Anything that gets dissolved would be consecutive. Unless you have a cross street issue, in which case I think there's a duplicate around here somewhere.

Comment: Oops, I assumed along a road and you might mean a stream or something else. Obviously addresses won't do any good if they don't relate to the line. But the dissolve idea above and linear referencing still do. There is the question of whether there are gaps between parcels though for the dissolve approach.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is to use your line to generate a Linear Referenced Route with the [Create Route tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003m00000005000000) and then use the [Locate Features Along Route tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003m00000007000000) to create line event segments where your polygons intersect the line.  This will create events that have the Line Route ID and a From and To measure of the relative position where the polygon intersection that created the line event falls along the route.  The table can be sorted by Route ID and then by either or both of the From or To measure to see the polygon attributes ordered by where they are along each Route line (If you had more than one line to intersect).  Consecutive line event records with the same route ID will be next to each other or nearest to each other along the route line.

I assume your parcels have a unique parcel ID field that will be preserved in the event attributes, so that you can join or relate the sorted events back to the parcel they originated from.  These line segments can be formally sorted with the [Sort tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000057000000) and then the sort output ObjectID can act as a unique ordered numbering of the parcel intersections along the line.  The relationship of your parcels to the line events they create on the Route can be a one to many relationship, but in general it should mostly be a one to one relationship where you could join and calculate the Route ID, measures and sorted ObjectID back to the parcels so that the original parcels can also be sorted in this order.

If the line is only near the parcels and does not actually cross the parcels you will first have to use the Buffer tool on the parcels to make the parcels actually intersect the line.  The tolerance setting of the Locate Features Along Route tool will be ignored for polygons, so it cannot be used as a substitute for the Buffer tool.

A few notes.  It is wise to explicitly set the [M Resolution](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/M_Resolution/001w0000000n000000/) and [M Tolerance](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/M_Tolerance/001w0000000p000000/) geoprocessing environment settings before running the tools and including a decimal point in the values with trailing zeros to indicate to the tool that you want decimal measure values generated.  Otherwise it may only generate whole number measures, which normally don't work well.

Answer (score 1):

1. Intersect your line (assumed single line, name in TOC=line) with polygons, output - polyline, e.g. INTRSCT.
2. Apply multipart to single part to INTRSCT, output SEGMENTS
3. Create numeric field in SEGMENTS table, e.g. CHAINAGE
4. Calculate field using code block (Python):

   ```
   def Chainage(shp):
       mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
       layers=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"line")
       lr=layers[0]
       with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lr, 'Shape@') as cursor:
         for row in cursor:
            geom=row[0]
       p=shp.positionAlongLine(50,True).firstPoint
       L=geom.measureOnLine  (p)
       return L
   ```

and

```
Chainage(!SHAPE!)
```

This will populate the field with distances of midpoint segements along the line.

Sort segment table by this field to see where changes of owner occur.